# Can't access controller nore action in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my Zend Framework project I have the following base URL

```
http://domain/~myFolder
```

If I access it like so, I can access the indexAction with no problem but if I try to access it explicitly like so:

```
http://domain/~myFolder/index
```

I can't, nore can I access different controllers or actions.
It always says

```
/public/index.php was not found on this server.
```

How can I access the different controllers and actions in my project? Do I need to add a route?

Comment: check the folder permission of `public` and if a `.htaccess` exists and is writeable. by default apache adds `.php` to a non-existent file like `index`, if it does not find either, it throws a 404

Comment: and how do I solve this problem? .htaccess is only readable

Comment: No need for write-permission on .htaccess file. Your problem is due to your script location. You should add this line `RewriteBase /~myFolder/` just below the `rewriteEngine On`. Nevertheless, it is a good practice to create a virtual host for your new environement.

Comment: Thank You, If you want you can write this as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Change the contents of the `.htaccess` file according to...

From: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.quick-start.html

> You may note that the application environment constant value looks for
>   an environment variable "APPLICATION_ENV". We recommend setting this
>   in your web server environment. In Apache, you can set this either in
>   your vhost definition, or in your .htaccess file. We recommend the
>   following contents for your public/.htaccess file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to access the controller page by putting the controller name after the `index.php`:

ie: `yoursite/public/index.php/ControllerName`

It worked in my case.